# How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, c++, .net, .net-assembly

I found an article entitled
How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005
It was recommended to me by a colleague because I found a useful C# library that would require quite a lot of work to port to C++ (I estimate 2-3 weeks).

The article is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736/en-us
I'm still trying to create the part that exports a function from C# so I can call it from
C++
The entire code of main.cs  is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

//Interface declaration
public interface ICalculator
{
   int Add(int Number1, int Number2);
};

//Interface Implementation


public class ManagedClass:ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int Number1, int Number2)
   {
    return Number1 + Number2;
    }
}
```

assemblyinfo.cs is this

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("sManagedDLL")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("sManagedDLL")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("5a30f24d-c60b-49fe-9943-afe862741030")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
```

unfortunately, it seems to have at least one error: the project called sManagedDLL suddenly seems to drop its initial "s" when regasm.exe is called.

I'm working with VS 2008 and Windows 7 on a 64 bit machine.

When I tried to call regasm.exe I got a message cannot find sManagedDLL.dll or one of its dependencies. So I launched dependency walker to look at the DLL created. I got the following error messages

```
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: OK I found what seems to be the solution: I used [link]http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/ to open a command prompt that gives me administrative priviledges, then I navigate to the directory where the dll is and i typed the regasm command (using  the full path for regasm) . It worked then. Previously I had written a batch file with the appropriate command and run that with admin privileged, but it was not finding the right dependencies apparently.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem of launching regasm, but the class  called ManagedClass appears to be unregistered when viewed from a CPPClient program. The platforms of the C++ client and the C# program are "32 bit" and "Any platform". I also did a search for the UUID in the registry and found it inside HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Comment: Final breakthrough: it turns out that if I use regasm from version 2.0 then the class is recognised by the CPP client as "registered" but not so if I use the latest version. My suspicion is that if I used a 64 bit platform in the projects I would have to use the later version of regasm.exe.